# Получение массива чисел от 1 до 4 в случайном порядке

Tags: java

Необходимо получить массив размером 4, значения элементов которого находятся в диапазоне от 1 до 4 и не повторяются.

Т.е. массив должен быть, например, `3 1 4 2` или `1 3 4 2.`

Каков оптимальный алгоритм для решения задачи?

Comment: Обычно такие задачи решаются перемешиванием массива из 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: либо в данном случае можно сгенерировать все 24 перестановки ручками и потом обычным random  выбирать один из них. Это один из самых быстрых способов в  данном случае. Для 6- и более элементов уже не подходит.

Comment: Почему? Прекрасно подходит. Генерируем случайное от 1 до макс. количества, и разворачиваем номер в вариант. Генерить все варианты вове не обязательно.

Comment: А какой у вас критерий оптимальности?

Answer (score 8):

Можно использовать статический метод shuffle класса Collections:

```
ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    data.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(data);
```

И дальше можно c помощью data.toArray() получить необходимый массив.

Comment: Интересный вариант, спасибо, протестирую на "случайность" его.

Comment: @Александр этот метод реализует алгоритм тасования Фишера-Йетса

Answer (score 7):

Используя один из вариантов [тасования Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
      int swap = array[index];
      array[index] = array[i];
      array[i] = swap;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

В дополнение к варианту с тасованием массива, ещё один, не требующий предварительного заполнения массива:

```
int n = 4;
int[] a = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  int j = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = i + 1;
}
```

Ещё одно преимущество такого подхода - в процессе перетасовки можно увеличить размер массива (с корректировкой переменной n).

Если же нужна последовательность начиная с нуля, то можно в предпоследней строке убрать `+ 1`.

[Ссылка на рабочий пример.](https://repl.it/EylJ/1)

Comment: Интересненько. Не ожидал, что работает. А с вероятностями точно всё хорошо?

Comment: @Qwertiy думаю, что не хуже чем Фишера-Йетса, т.к. это его [вывернутый вариант](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0#.C2.AB.D0.92.D1.8B.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.83.D1.82.D1.8B.D0.B9.C2.BB_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC).

Comment: @Qwertiy протестировал на 100 миллионах прогонах кода. Вероятности почти не отличаются от 0.25, так что всё нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, рассмотрю вариант на быстродействие, относительно других алгоритмов

Comment: @Александр "вывернутый" алгоритм, равно как и современный алгоритм из моего ответа, работает за линейное время. Для массива из 4 элементов разницы в быстродействии вы не заметите. Более долгую работу вариантов с `IntStream` и `Collections.shuffle`, думаю, можно заметить, только если запустить код тысячи раз.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
private static int[] getArray(int dimension) {
    Random random = new Random();
    return IntStream
            .generate(() -> random.nextInt(dimension) + 1)
            .distinct()
            .limit(dimension)
            .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Криво, замедляет программу, но можно так:

```
public class Name {
static int items = 4;
static int wait = 500;
static List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    for (int id = 0; id < items; id++)
        new Rand(id).start();

    Thread.sleep(wait);
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
        System.out.println(a.get(i));

}

public static synchronized void addA(int i) {
    a.add(i);
}

static class Rand extends Thread {
    int id;

    public Rand(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(wait));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        addA(id);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: В двух словах: стартуем items потоков, они по мере завершения добавляют в массив "a" значения, равные их же id (id даётся по очерёдности создания потоков)