# как поместить на случайные индексы в массиве конкретные числа

Tags: java, массивы

Только начинаю изучать java, данный код более-менее понятен

```
int n = 4;
int[] a = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  int j = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = i + 1;
}
```

По логике задачи нам надо расположить КОНКРЕТНЫЕ (даны четыре числа) элементы массива в случайном порядке, т.е. метод `rand.nextInt` не подойдет, верно? Нам надо выбирать из 4-ёх конкретных чисел.

Comment: чем вас не устроил такой ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609781/282277

Comment: если я правильно понял, но возможны дубликаты . int[]  p =   {12,4,67,5};
   int [] r =   new int[p.length]; 
    for (int i =0 ;i<p.length;i++) {
       r[i] = p[new Random().nextInt(3)]; 
     }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));

Comment: ух ты!!!! здорово , СПАСИБО большущее, кстати да, возможно повторение, а это не правильно. Сам бы не догадался, получается мы рандомно выбираем данные из первого массива.

Answer (score 0):

Фактически это задача о случайном перемешивании элементов заданного массива.  Код, представленный в вопросе, *генерирует* массив из `n` чисел от 1 до `n`, расставленных случайным образом, при помощи присваивания `a[j] = i + 1;`.

Следовательно, если задан некий массив исходных значений `p`, то достаточно брать значения из него:

```java
int[] p = {4, 5, 23, 34};
int n = p.length;
int[] a = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  int j = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = p[i];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p) + " --> " + Arrays.toString(a));
// [4, 5, 23, 34] --> [23, 5, 4, 34]
// [4, 5, 23, 34] --> [5, 23, 34, 4]
```

Если известна некая функция для генерации исходных значений в зависимости от индекса `i`, можно использовать её `a[j] = fun(i);`

---

Другие стандартные способы перемешивания массива чисел:

- Если массив определён как `Integer[]`, проще использовать сочетание стандартных методов: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arrIntegers));`:
  `Arrays.asList` создаст нерасширяемый список на основании заданного массива, и действия над элементами списка будут отражаться на соответствующие элементы  исходного массива.
- Если массив определён как массив примитивов `int[]`, то можно переставить его элементы вручную, используя [алгоритм Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC).
  В данном коде также показано, как можно переставить значения внутри массива без использования вспомогательной переменной при помощи побитовой операции XOR `^`.

```java
public static void shuffle(int[] arr) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = arr.length; i-- > 0;) {
        int r = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
        arr[r] = arr[r] ^ arr[i] ^ (arr[i] = arr[r]);
    }
}
```